# OpenGL Cube weird bug

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, cube, vertex

I am rendering a simple VBO cube in LWJGL, OpenGL. 6 quads with the correct normals, vertexes and RGB colors. However, I get a weird bug.

[image: Weird cube VBO bug]

Any ideas on what could cause this bug?

Thanks!

Edit: Cube drawing code:

```
glPushMatrix();
              GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer_id);
              GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 40, 0);
              GL11.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, 40, 12);
              GL11.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 40, 24);
              GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, vertex_data_array.length / 10);
              glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: post your code please. just the one where you draw the cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. My zNear was set to 0.00001. For some reason it worked fine when I changed it to 0.01. Thanks all :)

Comment: Probably what's happening is, if you're not culling the back faces, depending on the values you're using for the near and far clipping planes, you could experience some imprecision in your zbuffer, which would result in the the cube faces in the back bleeding through the ones in the front near the edges. Check out section 12.050 here: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm